# User data is unavailable with useUser in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, supabase, supabase-js

I'm trying to use the `useUser` hook from Supabase to fetch the user and then construct a query using the user id but the first time the page loads, I get a runtime error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Source
pages/users/[id].js (52:30) @ id

  50 |   .select()
  51 |   .eq("user_id", id)
> 52 |   .eq("follower_id", user.id);
```

When I refresh, it works fine (I assume because the useUser hook has had time to fetch the user). This is the relevant code snippet.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import supabase from "../../lib/supabase";
import { useUser } from "@supabase/auth-helpers-react";

function User({ props }) {
  const [follows, setFollows] = useState(false);
  const user = useUser();

  const checkFollowStatus = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("follows")
      .select()
      .eq("user_id", id)
      .eq("follower_id", user.id);
    if (!error && data) {
      console.log(data);
      setFollows(true);
    } else {
      setFollows(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkFollowStatus();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the `user` exists before calling `checkFollowStatus`, see this example https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-helpers/nextjs#client-side-data-fetching-with-rls

In your case:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) checkFollowStatus();
  }, [user]);
```